# jQUery dialog hide effect repeat?

Tags: jquery

I load dynamically a page which contains that dialog declaration:

```
$("#promo-code-modal").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    minHeight: 500,
    minWidth: 500,
    maxHeight:500,
    maxWidth:500,
    resizable: false,
    show: { 
        effect:"scale",
        speed:1000
    },
    hide: { 
        effect:"scale",
        speed:1000
    }
});
```

If I load that page for the second time (or more), during the `close` event, I see two times (or more) the `scale` effect in `hide` function. Why ?

Comment: It's called [FOUC](http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/) ...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are creating one dialog each time you reload your page try something like:

```
$("#promo-code-modal").clone().dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    minHeight: 500,
    minWidth: 500,
    maxHeight:500,
    maxWidth:500,
    resizable: false,
    show: { 
    effect:"scale",
    speed:1000
    },
    hide: { 
    effect:"scale",
    speed:1000
    },
    close: function(){
    $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
    }
});
```

Hope it works for you.